# Find support of a wavelet

Tags: wavelets

I am a complete novice in wavelet analyses, but I was given a task to find a support set of a given wavelet (in 1D, e.g. db4). Please, point me a way of doing this. (Since, how I understood from some research, the support is shift-able, it is needed to find only its length, am I right?)

Answer (score 1):

You have to study the refinement equation. Assume finite support and compare the support intervals on both sides.

---

For D4, the refinement equation reads as

$$\phi(x)=a_0\phi(2x)+a_1\phi(2x-1)+a_2\phi(2x-2)+a_3\phi(2x-3)$$

Assume that for some finite interval $\operatorname{supp} \phi\subset [a,b]$. Then interesting things in $\phi(2x-k)$ only happen when $x\in[\frac12(a+k),\frac12(b+k)]$. For equality of the enclosing intervals on both sides, $a=\frac12 a$ and $b=\frac12(b+3)$ are necessary, from which one finds $[a,b]=[0,3]$.

Comment: It should be $a_3 \phi(2x-3)$

Comment: Of course. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

For orthogonal wavelet systems, length of the support always is one less than the number of coefficients in the refinement equation [see, page 67](http://books.google.com.tr/books?id=0bp2mECxUJ0C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false).

For the case of D4, your wavelet family has the support $[0,3]$ and its length is 3. If you want to find the support of $\phi(2^jx-k)$ then it is:
$$supp(\phi)=\left [\frac{0+k}{2^j},\frac{3+k}{2^j}\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

The support of a wavelet is quite different. You should know which kind of wavelet you interest, then, you can check the wavelet information in MATLAB by command waveinfo. For Db$N$ wavelets ($N$ is positive integer), the support length is $2N-1$. The number of coefficietns is $2N-1$. Hope this helps!